# toJSON method is ignored when populating sub documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I need to remove certain fields from the JSON response. I've used the `toJSON()` method for doing this. Here is the code of my modal method for it.

```js
    User.methods.toJSON = function () {
      let obj = this.toObject()
    
      delete obj.resetPasswordToken
      delete obj.resetPasswordExpire
      delete obj.otp
      delete obj.otpExpire
      return obj
    }
```

The above code is working fine but when I populate the User modal with my Media model it doesn't remove the fields that I deleted from the JSON response.

```js
    const allMedia = await Media.find({}).populate({
      path: 'uploadedBy', // this is the user document 
    })
```

This is the code I wrote for populating the user model with the media model. But the problem is User gets populated with Media but it doesn't ignore the fields that I deleted from `toJSON()` method.

```
    {
        "name": null,
        "sizes": [],
        "isPrivate": false,
        "_id": "61d6d1a1fcaf7337f6f186de",
        "path": "http://192.168.1.7:2121/uploads/2022/1/7b37e2bc-b313-4b08-abd6-101e99c36527.png",
        "uploadedBy": {
            "firstName": "abc",
            "lastName": "abc",
            "role": "ADMIN",
            "resetPasswordToken": "77bda3f7794d305d7771fc23d932e1e9922df02c71b02c3564ad46b22ceac27e",
            "resetPasswordExpire": "1640954443294",
            "otp": null,
            "otpExpire": null,
            "_id": "61ceea9ce989f2d986fa9c5c",
            "userName": "abc",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-31T11:33:48.066Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-31T13:08:36.245Z"
        },
        "createdAt": "2022-01-06T11:25:21.839Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T11:25:21.839Z"
    }
```

If anyone can help, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Apparently you do not assign the result from the function with the deleted properties to a new variable  so you end  up with the unmodified object ...

Comment: I agree, @R2D2.

But I don't know any way of returning the modified objects.

Comment: Though, I can make a middleware or a helper function to be called before returning the object. But I am looking for a better approach if there is any. @R2D2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `pre` hook for each query for `Media` schema.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const schema = new Schema(...);

schema.pre('find', function () {
  this.populate('uploadedBy');
  this.select('-resetPasswordToken -resetPasswordExpire -otp -otpExpire');
});
```

You can add new `pre` hooks for other queries, just like for the `find`.

You can find more details [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre).

Comment: I don't want to repeat it for all queries, so I am looking for something like middleware or utility function that can exclude it globally for all the queries.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Thanks, man! This is exactly what I needed. However, I may need to use other hooks as well. For e.g. findOne, findOneAndUpdate, update, etc. Just to make sure I don't expose those fields.

Comment: Welcome. Yeah, I added that you can do the same for other methods.

Comment: Yup, thanks bunch!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using Aggregation

```
const allMedia = await Media.aggragate([
  $lookup: {
    from: 'uploadedBy',
    localField: 'uploadedBy',
    foreignField: '_id',
    // your variable
    as: 'uploadedBy',
  },
  {
    $project: {
//removing the field you want to remove by attibuting a Zero
      resetPasswordToken:0,
      resetPasswordExpire: 0,
      otp:0,
      otpExpire:0
      // select the field you want to display 
      fieldYouWantoToDisplay: 1,
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: This will remove the fields but I don't want to remove it for all the queries and that is the reason I've removed it globally from toJSON method. I've to repeat it for all queries If I do it using "aggregate" or "populate".